# Approximation by rectangles

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on some measurable space $\Omega = (\Omega ,\mathscr{F})$ and let $\mu\otimes\mu$ be its product measure on $\Omega \times \Omega = (\Omega \times \Omega, \mathscr{F}\otimes \mathscr{F})$. Then is it true that $1_E$ where $E\in \mathscr{F}\otimes \mathscr{F}$ can be approximated by a sequence of rectangles $1_{A\times B}$ where $A,B\in \mathscr{F}$?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true.

Just consider $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$ with the power set $\mathcal{F}$ and the measure $\mu(\{x\})=\frac{1}{3}$ for $x=1,2,3$. Clearly, the diagonal $$E=\{(x,x); x \in \Omega\}$$ is in $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}$. If there were sets $(A_n)_n \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and $(B_n)_n \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ such that $1_{A_n \times B_n} \to 1_E$ almost everywhere, then $$1_{A_n \times B_n} = 1_E$$ for sufficiently large $n$ (note that there are only finitely many points in $\Omega \times \Omega$ and only finitely many sets in $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}$). This, however, is impossible since the diagonal $E$ is not a  product set, i.e. it cannot be written in the form $A \times B$. Indeed, $(x,x) \in E$ would imply $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ for each $x \in \Omega$, i.e. $A=\Omega$ and $B=\Omega$, but clearly $E \neq \Omega \times \Omega$.

**Remark:** It is, however, true that for any $E \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}$ there exist simple functions of the form

$$f_n = \sum_{k=0}^{M(n)} c_k^{(n)} 1_{A_k^{(n)} \times B_k^{(n)}}$$

such that $f_n \to 1_E$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why simple functions of that form approximate $1_E$?

Comment: @AndrewYuan Take a look at the first result in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/106252).